# replicate phpmyadmin inline edit

Tags: inline, updating

I like the way phpMyadmin allows inline edit and I was thinking to implement it on my app. Do you know any similar jquery plugin which allows this functionality? Obviously update of the datebase is a must.

Many thanks!

Comment: use jQuery plugin Jeditable or Inline Text Edit

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Plugin Jeditable seems to be one of the more stable and updated versions of this kind of inline text editing.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable